# Is it possible to use a Kotlin-Native project as library in a Kotlin-JVM project?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

Is it possible to use a Kotlin-Native project as library in a Kotlin-JVM project? Basically what I want is to use Kotlin-Native instead of something like JNI or JNA.

So the project would look like this:

```
project
- application
  - runs on JVM
  - depends on native-lib and core, and other Java/Kotlin JVM libraries
- native-lib
  - contains platform-specific implementation
  - depends on core
- core
  - has no dependencies except maybe kotlin stdlib
  - contains common types so application and native-lib can share data
```

All I've found is [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/interoperability-between-kotlin-native-and-kotlin-jvm/5943/13) three year old thread, which says it's not possible yet, but will be. The [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-get-started.html) doesn't mention this option at all.

So, is there any update? I'd appreciate a link to the relevant documentation and/or examples.

And if this is *not* possible, how do I create JNI bindings so my JVM Kotlin code can use the Kotlin/Native code?